# How to make sure finger is actually on the screen with cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to test to make sure there is actually a finger on the screen every few seconds. Currently, I have things happening when ccTouchesBegan, though, what happens is you can turn off your device and turn it back on and it still thinks a finger is on the screen, or at least the functions are still going. Is there a way to prevent this? Like creating an @selctor to test this?

Comment: when app enters background its safe to assume there is no finger on the screen, so you should just clear your flags at that point

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do....

In my implementation, I would create a bool called 'isItStillBeingTouched'

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer

@property bool isItStillBeingTouched; // Should be fine anywhere between interface & end

@end
```

Although you haven't said, I'm guessing that you have loops that are performing the task(s) you want to achieve, hence why they are not stopping of their own accord. What you may try is to wrap it all in a Do While loop:

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isItStillBeingTouched = YES;

    while (isItStillBeingTouched) {

        // Your current code....
    }
}
```

You'll need to access the `isItStillBeingTouched` `bool` of your HelloWorldLayer class, from the AppDelegate, so alter said class to include this method within the helloWorldLayer.m

```
+ (id)sharedManager {
 static HelloWorldLayer *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Then in the HelloWorldLayer.h, insert `+(id)sharedManager;` anywhere tidy between your `@interface HelloWorldLayer` and your `@end` statements. *Not* inside any `{` or `}`.

The next step is to change the `bool` isItStillBeingTouched to `NO` when the application goes into the background.

Goto your AppDelegate.m, and find the:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
```

Alter this to include setting your `isItStillBeingTouched` `bool` to NO (within the if statement), and your methods should stop running.

You do this by first calling an instance of the HelloWorldLayer, and then changing the property to `NO`. For that you'll need to add `#import "HellowWorldLayer.h"`

Assuming you've never previously altered the AppDelegate, it should look something like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "IntroLayer.h"
#import "HellowWorldLayer.h"

//...The stock appDelegate code...

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
    {
        [director_ stopAnimation];
        HelloWorldLayer *myLocalInstanceOfTheHelloWorldLayerClass;
        myLocalInstanceOfTheHelloWorldLayerClass.levelToLoadUp = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to give you the answer, but I'm confused of how you'd get isStillBeingTouched to the AppDelegate.

Comment: I've now updated the answer, I hope this helps... any issues let me know. thanks

Comment: Still not working...I'm getting an error on "myLocalInstanceOfTheHelloWorldLayerClass.levelToLoadUp"

Comment: “Property 'levelToLoadUp' not found on object of type 'HelloWorldLayer *'”

Comment: Sorry my bad... I've edited the answer to show that the bool should be declared as a property on the header so instances may access it as we are in the call from the AppDelegate... Hope this solves it...! we will get there! lol

Comment: I'll check if this works soon, I'm sorry, I haven't had time lately, I just wanted to update you though. And yes! We will get there!

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Sadly...this has still not fixed the problem and I am getting the same error.